# Не понимаю логику передачи параметров функции

Tags: python

Наверное многим известен пример:

```
def foo(a=[]):
    a.append(1)
    print (a)

foo()
foo()
foo()
```

который выдает на печать:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

а я ожидал увидеть три одинаковых вывода -

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

Можете объяснить причину такого поведения?
Неужели функция хранит между вызовами свои объекты?

Comment: связанный вопрос ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/4279)

Comment: "Значения агрументов по умолчанию определяются только раз при создании функции и сохраняются в свойстве func_defaults" - https://habrahabr.ru/post/123821/ на русском.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что значение аргумента по умолчанию вычисляется только один раз - при объявлении функции и впоследствии при каждом вызове используется именно этот вычисленный объект. Если этот объект по какой-то причине меняется, то при следующих вызовах функции будет использовано уже новое значение.

То есть, иными словами, запись

`def foo(a=[]):`

Обозначает вовсе не "При каждом вызове функции аргументом будет пустой список", а "При каждом вызове аргументом будет вот этот вот конкретный список, который пока пуст, но вполне может стать и не пустым в будущем".

Именно по этой причине крайне не рекомендуется в качестве аргументов по умолчанию брать мутабельные объекты.